# Is it possible to import all exports in a module and target one or more of them at the same time?

Tags: typescript, es6-modules

Let's say I have a module defined here:

```
// math.ts
export function mult() {
}

export function add() {
}

export function sub() {
}
```

Then, in my client code, I want to get an object reference to all of these methods, as well as extract one of them by name, like this:

```
// index.ts
import * as math from "./math"
import {add} from "./math"
```

Is there any possible configuration or syntax for either my import or my module declaration that will allow me to combine those two lines? Like this:

```
import * as math, {add} from "./math"
```

or even better:

```
import Math, {add} from "./math"
```

I can't seem to find any documentation online that demonstrate how to do this for either Typescript or es6, but you do see it out in the wild eg:

https://github.com/ashsvendsen26/ChatComponent/blob/1c598703fd53a461e3e065859c258b0c555255a6/src/App.js#L1

Edit:
This technically works the way I want, but I don't like it because I have to repeat each function name in the module. How can it be tidied up so that I don't have to repeat myself?

```
export function add() {

}

export function sub() {

}

export function mult() {

}

export default {
    add,
    sub,
    mult
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults, which is to say, you don't have a default export in `math.ts`, so you can't import the default export in the way you want. You'll want to define a default export that encompasses everything in the file.

Comment: Thanks, adding a default export is definitely required. See my edit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this approach:

```
// _math.ts
export function add() {
}

export function sub() {
}

export function mult() {
}

// math.ts
import * as math from "./_math";
export * from "./_math";
export default math;
```

Then I can do this to import:

```
import Math, {add} from "math";
```

It's a bit clunky that you have to contrive an extra file, but it's a one-time annoyance and I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
// math.ts
export function mult() {
}

export function add() {
}

export function sub() {
}
```

then

```
//client.js
import * as math from "./_math";
const {default: Math, add} = math;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not much better than what I suggested in my own original post. Still two lines.